# Как в Linux включить заморозку системы, и перенаправить изменения в ОЗУ?

Tags: linux, readonly

Подобно DeepFreeze или ShadowDefender на Windows

Comment: Читайте топик о проблеме XY - ваш вопрос настолько странный (перенос костылей с форточки на линукс), что ответить на него невозможно без уточнений https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy/710#710

Comment: лучше опиши, что эти утилиты делают... на вскидку, после просмотра вики по диагонали, можно просто смонтировать в корень через unionfs tmpfs+реальный корень...

Comment: а на лвм можно снапшот сделать и потом его или применить или отбросить)